# regular expression in python: best way to change "a-b-cde" into ['a', 'b', 'cde']

Tags: python

I have an index where words are split in syllabes in the form 'foo-bar' and I want to create the list `['foo', 'bar']`.

I am new to python, and especially to the `re` module. So do I ask for the best way to do this instead of writing ugly code.

Comment: No need to use `re` at all, just try `my_list = my_string.split('-')`

Comment: why don't you do spliting on -?

Comment: @Selcuk : awsome! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of using any module. Use the inbuilt string split method.

```
a = "a-b-cde"
b = a.split('-')
#b contains ['a','b','cde']
```